# Select where number equals Infinity

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL, how to select the rows of a table where a column (datatype : `number`) equals `Infinity` on Oracle 10g ?

```
select * from MYTABLE where MYCOLUMN = Infinity;
```

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: @Sasse It's a `number`.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I would guess "MYCOLUMN is INF" would work.

Comment: **Update** for 12.1 - insert Infinity in `NUMBER`column raise `ORA-01426`, so the query works, but will return no result. The datatype must be `BINARY_FLOAT` to cover Infinity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Laurent Schneider](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/08/positive-infinity.html):

```
select * from MYTABLE where MYCOLUMN = binary_double_infinity;
```

Or with an implicit cast, just:

```
select * from MYTABLE where cast(MYCOLUMN as binary_double) = binary_double_infinity;
```

Or using [the `is infinite` floating point condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/conditions003.htm):

```
select * from MYTABLE where cast(MYCOLUMN as binary_double) is infinite;
```

I would attach an SQL Fiddle, but as Laurent noted, "expect a lot of bugs with your oracle clients"; this works in SQL Developer, but SQL Fiddle gets a numeric overflow.

Comment: Good, I was not aware of `is infinite`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - neither was I until a few minutes ago and experimented to see why `is inf` didn't work *8-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's see first how to get **`Infinity`** :

```
SQL> SELECT 1/0F COL FROM DUAL
  2  /

       COL
----------
       Inf
```

Now, let's look at the comparison :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1/0F COL FROM DUAL)
  3  SELECT * FROM data WHERE col = binary_double_infinity
  4  /

       COL
----------
       Inf
```

**Update** : Thanks to **Alex**, the `is infinite` clause is also an option.

I am on `12.1.0.1`.

The same query with `is infinite` clause :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1/0F COL FROM DUAL)
  3  SELECT * FROM data WHERE col is infinite
  4  /

       COL
----------
       Inf
```

Comment: As the `is infinite` tests for both positive and *negative* infinity, an additional predicate `and n > 0` should be added to get the same result as for `col = binary_double_infinity`.